# Calculating area of from 10x10 degree tiff raster file using QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, geotiff-tiff, area

I am new to QGIS.

How do I calculate the area in 0.05x0.05 cells from a 10x10 tiff raster file?

I guess I will have to do a loop function to get the areas from the 10x10 file but I have no idea how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Starting with a small raster grid:

[image]

Use "Raster pixels to polygons" to create a polygon grid with rectangles round each pixel:

[image]

Now you can get the area, which is accessible via the "$area" expression for things like labelling:

[image]

giving this which shows the irregularity in area of a grid defined in lat-long.

[image]

To make a new raster with these values:

- Use the attribute table to add a new column called "area" to the rectangle polygons.
- Use the field calculator to set those values to "$area". That should set the column to the true area value.
- Use "Rasterize (overwrite with attribute)" to burn the "area" value from the rectangles into the raster. Note this overwrites the raster so make a copy and work on that:

[image]

I end up with this:

[image]

which is expected because my area only depends on latitude.

I'm not sure why there's not a simple function to compute a raster of the cell areas of a given raster but maybe I've missed it.

In R its one function to compute the area of each cell and another to turn it into a matrix so you can see the values:

```
> as.matrix(area(r))
         [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]
[1,] 1025.648 1025.648 1025.648 1025.648
[2,] 1025.717 1025.717 1025.717 1025.717
[3,] 1025.752 1025.752 1025.752 1025.752
```